# How to reverse duplicate value in multidimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, iteration

I have a dictionary (multidimensional?) like this:

```
d = { 0: [3, 5], 1: [5, 7], 2: [4, 7], 3: [4, 3] }
```

I would like to find any duplicate matching position (0) or (1) value in the dictionary lists and if there is a duplicate then reverse the second matching pair of numbers.

The dictionary would become:

```
{ 0: [3, 5], 1: [5, 7], 2: [7, 4], 3: [4, 3] }
```

Only position (0) would be a duplicate of position (0), and only position (1) would be a duplicate of position (1) if that makes sense. There can only be one duplicate in a series and all of the numbers should chain together after the deduplication/flipping prcoess. Below illustrates:

```
[0 , 1] [1 , 2] [2 , 3] [3 , 0]
```

I'm trying to match up all adjacent position (1)'s with position (0)'s, so the values essentially go full circle (think of it as a series of lines that connect from one end to the other). I'm open to using anything like numpy, etc. that might help efficiently tackle this issue. Here's another example:

```
{ 'foo': [2, 9], 'bar': [3, 2], 'baz': [3, 9] }
```

Which should end up:

```
[2, 9], [9, 3], [3, 2]
```

I've tried a bunch of things like:

```
l = list(sorted(d.values()))

for i in range(0, len(l)):
    # now what the heck?
```

Comment: Is the result supposed to be a dict with the original keys like your first example, or an ordered list of connected edges like your second example?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Hi John, it's supposed to be an ordered list of connected edges. The dictionary indexes really don't matter so much since I'll be ordering the final result according the edges. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you totally don't care about key, and assure pair-values will make a complete circle. I think you can try this:

Store the two neighbors of every number by dict(enhance query performance), and start from any number, then go through the circle chain, until it reach itself again.

```
def reverse_pairs(input_dict):
    pair_values = list(input_dict.values())
    neighbors = defaultdict(list)

    for num1, num2 in pair_values:
        neighbors[num1].append(num2)
        neighbors[num2].append(num1)

    res = [pair_values[0]]
    while res[0][0] != res[-1][1]:
        a1, b1 = res[-1]
        a2, b2 = neighbors[b1]
        res.append([b1, a2 if a1 != a2 else b2])

    return res
```

test case:

```
def test():
    dict1 = {0: [3, 5], 1: [5, 7], 2: [7, 4], 3: [4, 3]}
    print(reverse_pairs(dict1))

    dict2 = {'foo': [2, 9], 'bar': [3, 2], 'baz': [3, 9]}
    print(reverse_pairs(dict2))
```

output:

```
[[3, 5], [5, 7], [7, 4], [4, 3]]
[[2, 9], [9, 3], [3, 2]]
```

Hope that will help you, and comment if you have further questions. : )

Answer (score 2):

A set of pairs like this that forms a chain has the property that each element appears exactly once in the first position of a pair and once in the second position. If you know you have exactly one reversal amongst your pairs you can take advantage of this property: the first element in the reversed pair appears twice in the first position and the second element does not appear at all in the first position.

Here's the idea: examine the pairs one by one and track each pair by its first element. When we see a second pair with the same first element, one of these two pairs must be the reversed one - call these candidates. When we see the *second* element of one of the candidates as the first element of another pair, we know that candidate is not the reversed one, so we reverse the other one.

This solution works in-place, which may or may not be an advantage. It would be easy to convert to one that returns a corrected list. It also has the advantage that it only goes through the list of pairs once - in the worst case. In most cases it can stop before the end. It's about seven times faster than the solution from [recnac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55556796/9200529) in my testing.

```py
def fix_chain(pair_dict):
    first_to_pair = dict()
    this, that = None, None # candidates
    for pair in pair_dict.values():
        if pair[0] in first_to_pair: # found the collision
            this = pair
            that = first_to_pair[pair[0]]
        else:
            first_to_pair[pair[0]] = pair
        if this and this[1] in first_to_pair: # this is not reversed...
            that.reverse() # ... so that must be
            return
        if that and that[1] in first_to_pair: # that is not reversed...
            this.reverse() # ... so this must be
            return
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I will test it out when I get home and report back the results. What makes it about seven times faster than the other answer? I'm really curious.

Comment: Good question! I haven't profiled the other answer. I should note, though, that I was testing with lists of ten thousand up to millions of pairs. With a list of 10000 pairs the functions take 1 millisecond and 7 milliseconds respectively. Probably not of much practical importance :)